# Send Message to Discord server owner on-join

Tags: python, discord.py

I am wanting my bot to send a private message to the user who added my bot to a Discord server or the server owner. I have attempted this and cannot seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only resolve the owner of the server, not the person who invited you.  It would look something like:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_server_join(server):
    await client.send_message(server.owner, "I'm ready!")

client.run("YOUR TOKEN")
```

You can find the relevant event [in the documentation](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_server_join).